# Python Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm having a problem with some webscraping code that I'm trying to run. To scrape information from a series of links like the following:

http://www2.congreso.gob.pe/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2006.nsf/ec97fee42a2412d5052578bb001539ee/89045fe8ae896e2e0525751c005544cd?OpenDocument

I am trying to scrape certain elements from the table, but I received the following error:

```
Python Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I know this has to do with the fact that it's not actually finding the table because when I run the following simplified code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time

url = 'http://www2.congreso.gob.pe/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2006.nsf/ec97fee42a2412d5052578bb001539ee/89045fe8ae896e2e0525751c005544cd?OpenDocument'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


table = soup.find('table', {'bordercolor' : '#6583A0'})
print(table)
```

It returns a 'None' for the printed table, meaning the code cannot scrape any of the features of the table. I've been running similar code for similar pages and I am able to find the table just fine so I'm not sure why this is not working? I'm new to webscraping but I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: is the site blocked? can you visit the link? - i see no issue with your code

Comment: If you print out soup, you will see nothing. It seems beautifulsoup doesn't parse it correctly.

Comment: By viewing the page source, one of the script tag is incorrect, it's `</script `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the html contains some flaws that made the html parser fails to properlly parse your html, you can verify that by printing `page.text` and then print `soup`, you will find that the document has some parts removed by parser.

However lxml parser successfully parsed it with its flaw as `lxml` is better on ill-formatted html documents:

```
rom bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time

url = 'http://www2.congreso.gob.pe/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2006.nsf/ec97fee42a2412d5052578bb001539ee/89045fe8ae896e2e0525751c005544cd?OpenDocument'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')


table = soup.find('table', {'bordercolor' : '#6583A0'})
print(table)
```

that should catch the table tag correctly

Answer (score 1):

So the soup doesn't parse the website content correctly, because one tag is incorrect and break the structure. You have to fix it before parse it:

```
url = 'http://www2.congreso.gob.pe/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2006.nsf/ec97fee42a2412d5052578bb001539ee/89045fe8ae896e2e0525751c005544cd?OpenDocument'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text.replace("</script\n", "</script>"), 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'bordercolor' : '#6583A0'})
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(
    "http://www2.congreso.gob.pe/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2006.nsf/ec97fee42a2412d5052578bb001539ee/89045fe8ae896e2e0525751c005544cd?OpenDocument")[0]

print(df)
df.to_csv("Data.csv", index=False, header=None)
```

Output: [view online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/39dd88dca93b73a8fca39b157f017d84/data.csv)

[image]